# Folium adding an overlay (.geojson) to map

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, geojson, folium

This is what I have so far:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(
        location=[43.761539, -79.411079],
        tiles="Stamen Toner",
        zoom_start=11
        )

m.save("index.html")

folium.GeoJson("file.geojson").add_to(m)
m
```

Up until the `folium.GeoJson`... line the map shows up but the overlay makes nothing render

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `LayerControl()`:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(
        location=[43.761539, -79.411079],
        tiles="Stamen Toner",
        zoom_start=11
        )

folium.GeoJson("file.geojson", name="geojson").add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save("index.html")
m
```